# When a strictly positive log pluriharmonic function $g$ is equal to the norm of holomorphic function?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, singularity-theory, potential-theory, several-complex-variables

Suppose $V$ is a local analytic variety (singular). Suppose $g$ a strictly positive log pluriharmonic function on $V$, i.e. $\log g$ is pluriharmonic.  I wonder when $g=|f|^2$, where $f$ is a holomorphic function.

1. There is some ambiguity because I didn't define what is a pluriharmonic function on a singular variety. In fact, I'm not sure what is the definition in literature.
2. I assume this might be related to the singularity type of $V$. So I don't assume anything about the singularity type and leave it as a condition to be discussed.

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic and non-constant, $|f|^2$ is NOT pluriharmonic. So the answer on your question is "never".

Comment: I think you mean "plurisubharmonic". Also, calling $\vert f \vert^2$ the ``square of $f$'' feels weird.

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre, Nicolas. The question is edited.

Comment: I am not sure what a "local analytic (singular) variety" is, but if the punctured plane $C\backslash\{0\}$ qualifies, then $g(z)=|z|$ is a counterexample.